Installation error in DSAS v4.2_2 version compatible with ArcMap 10.3
DSASv4.2_2 version:
In the process of installing the DSAS 4.2 software, during installation the following error occurs:

Unable to get installer types in the Files Shoreline Analysis
System\DSAS.dll assembly. Unable to load one or more of the requested
types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

